# Multi-Target .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.5 fails due to missing .net 4.5 framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

On my dev box I have .net 4.6.2 and dotnet-sdk-2.1 installed. I originally had 4.0 then 4.5 then 4.6.2

I am able to run dotnet build on a project which multi-targets to both netstandard2.0 and net45 like this:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

I am able to build it successfully and run unit tests etc. I see the bin directory contains subdirectories for each target framework and contains all the DLLs.

When I try to put together my CI build on a teamcity agent which is built on Windows Server 2016. I get an error:

> The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found.

This is puzzling to me because the machine has .NET 4.6.2 SDK installed. (It also has the dotnet sdk 2.1 installed)

Doing some googling around I see many mentioning that the frameworks should be in the dictory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\
```

And when I check the Server 2016 machine I see the directory and I see subdirectory: **v4.6.2** no subdirectories for **4.5**

On my dev box however I see all kinds of directories there: 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 4.6.2 ...

I can't install framework 4.5 SDK on the Server 2016 machine because it already has a higher version installed. So it seems I can't build targeting .NET 4.5 on that machine.

As a sanity check I changed my csproj file to:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net462</TargetFrameworks>
```

And I was able to build the project successfully. So the build does work but it requires 4.6.2 on that machine. It does not work neither if I target `net46`.

What am I doing wrong here?
Is there a way for me to be able to multi-target my project to net45 on the Server 2016 machine?

Comment: As a side note, I need to target .NET 4.5 because of some legacy applications that will be using this library so I can't just settle for 4.6.2 unfortunately.

Comment: You need to install targeting pack for 4.5. I do not know where to download them separately, but you can obtain them as part of Visual Studio Build Tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: install the .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Pack to build .NET Framework 4.5 projects.

You say that your server has the .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack installed, and you are trying to build a .NET Framework 4.5 project with it.

Unlike runtime packs, where each version contains (so to speak) the previous version, you need to have the developer pack for the exact version of the framework you are targetting.

Comment: That was the very first thing I tried to do. However, whenever I try to install .NET 4.5 SDK Developer Pack, the installer tells me it can't install it because there is already a newer version of the framework already installed.

Comment: So looks like I was trying to install the Full .NET 4.5 framework which is why I was getting that message saying I can't install it because 4.6 is already there. I found this link: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net452-developer-pack which has the 4.5.2 developer pack. I was able to install it and build my app to 4.5.2. That's better, but now the question remains, is it possible to install developer pack for 4.5.0 or is that only part of the full framework (which I can't install) ?

Comment: @DKhanaf It seems that Microsoft took down the download links for 4.5 and 4.5.1., so there's not a lot that can be officially done. Check if the Visual Studio Installer doesn't give you that download option